# How To Write SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, derby

I have This table in which i wanted the unique bread id whichever comes first into the table i wanted it into the query result.

means in following scenario i wanted these records which has following id.

58 ,59 , 60 , 61 ,68 , 69

```
id  bread id                                        exception               time
58  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:1   null                    16:33.2
59  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:2   null                    17:18.7
60  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:3   null                    17:18.9
61  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:4   null                    17:19.0
62  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:4   jmsexception            17:20.1
63  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:4   jmsexception            17:20.1
64  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:4   jmsexception            17:20.1
65  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:4   jmsexception            17:20.1
66  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:4   jmsexception            17:20.5
68  ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:9   jmsexception            17:21.2
69  ID:D--113042539-54300-1363171861821-3:1:1:1:1   InvalidXPathExpression  22:28.1
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  Also, which SQL flavor is it (MySQL, T-SQL, etc)?

Comment: have you tried anything? what goes wrong?

Comment: Actually, the flavour of sql does not matter here.  It's a simple min().

Comment: @user2032008 - From what I could find out (http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/SQLvsDerbyFeatures) **Derby** SQL does not support "windowing", so you will need to use correlated sub-query (which seem to be supported).  If you need just IDs (and not entire rows), then `GROUP BY` and `MIN()` will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5b31/7)**

```
SELECT `t1`.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT MIN(t.id)
               FROM Table1 t
               WHERE t.`bread id`= t1.`bread id`)
```

Result:

```
| ID |                                      BREAD ID |              EXCEPTION |    TIME |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 58 | ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:1 |                 (null) | 16:33.2 |
| 59 | ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:2 |                 (null) | 17:18.7 |
| 60 | ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:3 |                 (null) | 17:18.9 |
| 61 | ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:4 |                 (null) | 17:19.0 |
| 68 | ID:D--113042539-54026-1363171110733-3:1:1:1:9 |           jmsexception | 17:21.2 |
| 69 | ID:D--113042539-54300-1363171861821-3:1:1:1:1 | InvalidXPathExpression | 22:28.1 |
```